# Aditional SQLite syntax highlighting in Vim

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlight

Currently I'm editing some SQLite scripts with my filetype set to `ft=sql` and some types aren't being highlighted and :

- REAL
- TEXT

There is some configuration that I'm missing ? I've searched for a syntax file specific for SQLite and didn't found any.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know Vim doesn't have special support for SQLite, but `mysql` should come pretty close for this purpose:

```
:SQLSetType mysql
```

For more information: `:help ft_sql.txt`.

Comment: Thanks, `:SQLSetType` was exactly what I needed.